# TFS Licensing - GIT repository access

Tags: git, tfs, cal

Quick question - is TFS CAL required for users to access only the TFS GIT source code repository? 
Assuming they will access only the source-code using Git Bash, and they won?t use any other TFS features and never even login to TFS website.

Our understanding is that Git is an open source system based on GNU license, so accessing it should not require any license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [software licensing is not on topic, as it is not a practical programming problem.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/7976758)

Comment: You should always talk to your account representative about pricing, but yes, your users require a license to use TFS.  That git is under the GPL is irrelevant: its license governs how you use the git software, not how you use Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, No.

There should be a server git repository and local git repository. For local git repository , you just need to make sure the user have windows folder permission. However, for server git repository, which is also host on TFS server. To access server side GIT repository, you also need TFS access.

> To license TFS , you’ll need a TFS server license and a Windows
>   operating system license (Windows Server is best) for each machine
>   running TFS, plus **a client access license for each person connecting
>   to TFS**. Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for people who
>   just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access, which is
>   free.

Only the **Stakeholder** access is free and **no need a CAL**. GIT repository access
is also belong to Code feature which at least need **[Basic access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels#basic-access)**

[image]

More details about access levels please refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels#basic-access) in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks but as far as I know it's all in SQL database. I don't see any way to access the GIT repository directly - bypassing TFS.